# Excel : Automate COUNTIF (based on another table)

Tags: excel, join, countif, sumifs

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name nation
aaa  ESP
bbb  FRA
ccc  ESP
ddd  BEL
eee  FRA
fff  ITA
```

I have another table with :

```
country count
ESP     -
BEL     -
FRA     -
ITA     -
```

I would like my "count" column of the second table to count how many instances I have of that nation in the first table.

So that I get :

```
country count
ESP     2
BEL     1
FRA     2
ITA     1
```

I could enter in each cell of the "count" column:

```
COUNTIF('my 1st table nation column',"name of the targeted country")
```

The thing is I have 150 countries and I can't possibly edit all the country codes in each and every cell of the "count" column.

I also tried this workaround:

I selected the first cell of "count" and then highlighted the whole column. Then I typed:

```
COUNTIF('my 1st table nation column',"name of the country of the first country cell")
```

This way, I expected each cell of the "count" column to refer to the name of the "country" of its table row.
But it didn't work.

Is there any other way (with a formula, not VB) I can automate the process so that each "count" cell reads its "country"  and swipes through the "nation" column and count how many instances there are ?

Thank you.

Comment: Make a unique list and then use data validation to feed the countif()?

Comment: Thanks. How would data validation target the desired country for each and every cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,"="&D2)
```

| name | nation |  | country | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | ESP |  | ESP | 2 |
| bbb | FRA |  | BEL | 1 |
| ccc | ESP |  | FRA | 2 |
| ddd | BEL |  | ITA | 1 |
| eee | FRA |  |  |  |
| fff | ITA |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use a Pivot Table, field `nation` into rows section and field `name` into values section.

That way you can make a list of unique countries and count how many instances of each you got in like 3 seconds....

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

No need of VBA.

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted another answer that didn't need a pivotable but your answer is very helpful. Thanks !